# How can I list the passed & failed test cases in the slack channel from a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for how to setup/configure the Jenkins job with Slack notification integration so that it will show both passed & failed test cases in the notification. I also need colour formatting for passed & failed test cases with percentages.

I am looking for how to set the Slack notification so that it should show which test cases passed & failed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Slack Notification plugin to integrate the jenkins with slack and get the notifications as per your requirement. Follow this official documentation for more information

https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/